# CSS: Checkbox with Border. How to get Space between Border and Content?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a checkbox:

```
<div class="row margin-top-15">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="checkbox_square">
            <input id="check_password_show" type="checkbox" value=""></input>
            <label for="check_password_show"></label>
        </div>
        <p th:text="#{label.common_password_show}"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And i created a custom checkbox style:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.checkbox_square {
    position: relative;
}

.checkbox_square label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid var(--textcolorsecundary);
}

.checkbox_square label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    background: var(--diagramGreenColor);
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid var(--primaryColor);
}

.checkbox_square label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.checkbox_square input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

It now looks like that unselected:

[image]

and that selected:

[image]

the selected state is a little bit different than i want it. I wish it would look like:

[image]

So what i need is some space between the green background and the blue border. Is that somehow possible?

I tried to create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qp4cx5z/2/) to show my checkbox but as you can see the checkbox is not showing up at all in jsFiddle. It is working fine in my IDE and Browser.

Comment: Can you create a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Oh i tried that already when i pasted in my code there was no checkbox showing up at all :(

Comment: I can't make this work using your code either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the positions of `.checkbox_square label:after` to achieve the desired effect. Check below example.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.checkbox_square {
  position: relative;
}
.checkbox_square label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
.checkbox_square label:after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.checkbox_square label:hover::after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.checkbox_square input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
.checkbox_square input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row margin-top-15">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="checkbox_square">
      <input id="check_password_show" type="checkbox" value="" />
      <label for="check_password_show"></label>
    </div>
    <p th:text="#{label.common_password_show}"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the solution im searching for because that way i cant change the border color to be blue after the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: Check the updated code. You can add `.checkbox_square input[type=checkbox]:checked + label` to change border color.